# Install the AWS Cloudwatch Agent from a S3 VPC endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

To keep our resources on AWS secure, we are trying to block access to the internet for our EC2 instances unless we explicitly need it. We have one EC2 instance (Ubuntu) running that we want to install the AWS [cloudwatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html) on. The default way to do this is to use wget to download the installation files from an s3-internal address (as seen in the linked article).

We now want to replace the public access our EC2 instance has to the internet with VPC endpoints. I created an interface endpoint for global S3 access and S3 access in our region each. Optimally, the EC2 instance would now connect through our endpoint to the S3 bucket to download the resources from the AWS address.

**How can I now access the files from my EC2 instance using wget?** The article lists an url option for the global s3 access and another url for regional S3 access, but I can not get a connection using either. Here's a few examples of urls I tried:

```
wget https://accesspoint.s3-global.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/ubuntu/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb

wget https://s3.vpce-123456.s3.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent-eu-central-1/ubuntu/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb

wget https://amazoncloudwatch-agent-eu-central-1.vpce-123456.s3.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
```

Note that `accesspoint.s3-global.amazonaws.com` is the internal private DNS entry created by the global s3 service endpoint (automatically), and `*.vpce-123456.s3.eu-central-1.vpce.amazonaws.com` is an example for one of the DNs entries created by the regional S3 service endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it with a private endpoint - I spend half of my day today banging my head against it. Couple of gotchas to be aware of:

1. The security group for the VPC endpoint requires a permissive egress rule. All TCP for the subnet IP addresses works.
2. You need PrivateDns enabled and PrivateDnsOnlyForInboundEndpoint disabled

It's very easy to trip up on the second point because you get a default value for the latter when you set the former, for example via terraform.

[This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/822979/how-to-verify-a-aws-vpc-s3-endpoint-works) helped me a lot to troubleshoot the issue. Use traceroute to understand what is not working.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have updated the route table of your subnet. Add the rule that routes the traffic to the endpoint gateway (since we are talking about S3).

Comment: note that we use interface endpoints (for example, to access aws logs via endpoint, these work). is it not possible to solve this issue using interface endpoints?